# Angular Universal - Replace Real Module with Mock Module

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-universal

Angular Universal does not come with webpack installed by default. However, I am wondering if there is a way to either lazy-load a module, or load a mock version to stop compile errors. With webpack, we do something like this:

```js
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');


module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            /module/,
           root('./client/app/shared/servermocks/my-module.mock.ts')
          )
    ]
};
```

I don't know how to install webpack without breaking my code (I assume it was removed for a reason).  However, is there a simpler way to do this using the default angular server file?

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/myModule/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine 
  // (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }) as any);

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just import the Mock module in `app-server.module.ts` ?

Comment: I could, but it will also import the regular module when it gets called.

Comment: have a `app.module`, `app-browser.module` and `app-server.module` files maybe, like here: https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/tree/master/src (not tested)

Comment: Those files are already there and part of Angular Universal.

Comment: Can't you add the real module to app-bower.module and the mock-module to app-server.module?

Comment: No, app.module either way, and app.server.module runs on top of that.  Either way, I need a compile way of doing it for ssr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  In **tsconfig.server.json** I can edit two options:

```js
    "paths": {
      "quill": ["src/app/quill.mock.server.ts"]
    }
```

and you have to add the file as well like so:

```js
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts",
    "src/app/quill.mock.server.ts",
  ],
```

Comment: Can you may be share your quill.mock.server.ts code? I am facing the same issue with quill

Comment: I don't use quill anymore, but you can see [here](https://github.com/jdgamble555/ngx-quill-ssr)